# $\hat{f}(\omega)=0$ and $f$ is continuous then $f(t)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is defined by: $g(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\hat{f}(\omega)\} $.

If the original $f$ is continuous, then $g(t)=f(t)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Question:- If,  $$\hat{f}(\omega)=0$$ then$$ f(t)=\ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\hat{f}(\omega)\}$$

$$f(t)= \mathcal{F}^{-1}({0})$$
$$f(t)=0.$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. To be more precise, $f$ is the zero element of $L^{1}$ which means it is $0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks. If $$\hat{f}(\omega_0)=0$$ f continuous then $f(t)=0$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, if it is continuous then it is $0$ at every point.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks. But the fourier transform is zero at a specific point $w_0$

Comment: @Shreyaanand It's nonsense to talk about the value of $\hat{f}$ at any specific point because it is a $L^1$ function.

Comment: No, if the function $\hat{f}$  is continuous and it is zero at a specific point, it need not follow that $f$ is zero anywhere.

Comment: for example the Fourier transform of $(|x|+1/2)e^{-|x|}$ (an everywhere non zero continuous function) has zeroes at $\pm \sqrt 3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. The Fejér kernel
$$\begin{equation}
F_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\left(1-\frac{|s|}{\lambda}\right)e^{isx}dx
\end{equation}$$

is an approximate identity for $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ thus
$\begin{equation}
\lim \limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \|F_{\lambda}*f-f\|_1=0
\end{equation}$ where
$$ F_{\lambda}*f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\hat{f}(s)\left(1-\frac{|s|}{\lambda}\right)e^{isx}dx.$$

Now since $\hat{f}\equiv 0$ one obtains $f\equiv 0.$ By continouity this means $f(t)=0\ \forall t\in \mathbb{R}.$

**Remark:**
For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is bounded and uniformly continous, so we can indeed evaluate $\hat{f}$ at any point $\omega_0\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @f af Thanks for the answer. So What can we say about a continuous function whose Fourier transform is 0 at a point $w_0 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @f af Please reply. I will give you a check mark.

Comment: hmm maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant the fourier transform was zero everywhere. For isolated zeros the implication doesn't hold.
My remark was targeted at the comment by Sam Wong for clarification.

Comment: @f af Can you please give me a reference for your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this was proved in the lecture and I´m afraid can't cite the script but here is a different script I found explaining approximate identities:
https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/7338/fall09/approxid.pdf
If you now show that the Fejér kernel, satisfies the Definition 1.51, then by theorem 1.53 you obtain the proof I gave you.